# Get value of an specific input-type-text with a checkbox and put them in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

In my example, the "textbox" is EMPTY, and must be filled in by the user.
The checkbox has to COPY what has been WRITTEN in the textbox (type="checkbox" value=written-text-on-profile-textbox)

When the checkbox is checked, I need it to take the text written in the `<input type="text" id="profile">` and with this text, the checkbox (if ckecked) need to create a URL.

```
<script src="https://videochatencasa.com/buton/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="your username" id="profile">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="gallery" name="gallery" value="PROFILE-TEXT">
```

```
nickname = $('#profile').val();
if (nickname != '') {
  text += "<a href='https://web.com/profile/" + nickname + "/'>Profile</a>\n";
}

nickname = $('#gallery').val();
if (nickname != '') {
  text += "<a href='https://web.com/profile/gallery/" + nickname + "/'>Gallery</a>\n";
}
```

Expected result:

Suppose the username written in the text box, HANNA, and the checkbox, is checked. In the HTML. these two links should be generated.

```
<a href='https://web.com/profile/HANNA'>Profile</a>
<a href='https://web.com/profile/gallery/hanna'>Gallery</a>
```

Full form is more complex - https://videochatencasa.com/buton/top0es.php - but is about the first 2 files (with black BG) so, the second file (checkbox) need to get the value from the first file (the first text box on the form)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working, what the problem is?

Comment: I cant get the text value of the textbox, by click on checkbox - thi is the form (first and second fies with black background) - https://videochatencasa.com/buton/top0es.php

Comment: can you create a small reproducible code on stackblitz or jsfiddle ?

Comment: What happens if the checkbox is unchecked? Does it remove the links? @vidchat

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a callback function for when the checkbox state is changed.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="gallery" name="gallery" onchange="checkboxChanged(this)" value="PROFILE-TEXT">
```

The onchange will call the checkboxChanged function when the state of the checkbox changes with "this" being the checkbox input tag

then,

```
const checkboxChanged = (tag) => {
    if (!tag.checked) return '';
    nickname = $('#profile').val();
    let text = ""

    if (nickname != '') {
        text += "<a href='https://web.com/profile/" + nickname + "'>Profile</a>\n";
        text += "<a href='https://web.com/profile/gallery/" + nickname.toLowerCase() + "'>Gallery</a>";
        console.log(text)
        // do stuff with text
    }
}
```

in checkboxChanged first, we will check if the checkbox is checked.
then, code is somewhat similar.
It produces the desired result.